# execute a python package from the shell step by step e.g. debugging mode

Tags: python, debugging, package, execution

I want to observe the data flow in a package that is executed in the shell. Is the freqtrade bot. I want to run it step by step so I can observe the dataflow. This have to be executed in the shell with some parameters e.g.:

"freqtrade trade -s strategy"

How could I do this from the shell or from vscode allowing me to go through each step, like if it was debugging mode (which I could not do for the package either)?

Comment: This is a duplicate question, evidenced by the comment above.

Comment: Why was this marked as a duplicate? And isn't the only answer useless? The whole point of the question is how to apply a debugger to the freqtrade library, which is not run with the python command (it's something with docker). It's not "does python have a debugger", clearly OP knows how to use a debugger

Comment: @moha any advances on this topic? I'm trying to debug freqtrade inside the container and there isn't a clear explanation on how to do it

Answer (score 0):

there is a debugger called *pdb*. Check [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html)